# R studio - how to paste chunks of code, but with comments removed?

Tags: r, rstudio, comments

Example code:

```
grid_moj <- expand.grid(
  a1 = seq(-5, 15, length=25), #comment here
  a2 = seq(1,3, length=25)
  ) %>% mutate(dist=map2_dbl(a1,a2, sim1_dist))
```

I want to copy and paste this code to tweak a few numbers. If I have a lenghty comment somewhere inside, is there a way to paste just the code while removing any comments?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`formatR` package](https://yihui.org/formatr/), which has a suite of tools to clean up files, pasted code, entire directories of R files, and even Shiny apps. The example below explicitly calls your text from above, but running `tidy_eval()` with no specified `source` or `text` defaults to using clipboard, so can be a simple method of doing this. Make sure to use `comment = FALSE` to remove comments.

```r
formatR::tidy_eval(text = "grid_moj <- expand.grid(
  a1 = seq(-5, 15, length=25), #comment here
  a2 = seq(1,3, length=25)
) %>% mutate(dist=map2_dbl(a1,a2, sim1_dist))", 
                   comment = FALSE)
#> grid_moj <- expand.grid(a1 = seq(-5, 15, length = 25), a2 = seq(1, 3, length = 25)) %>% 
#>     mutate(dist = map2_dbl(a1, a2, sim1_dist))
```